# combine(Flow...) is not working with 3 Flows

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'm trying to use `combine()` to combine 3 flows but nothing happens. This is my code:

```
combine(flowX, flowY, flowZ) { x, y, z ->
    println("$x, $y, $z") // this line is never reached
}
```

I know my flows are good because this works:

```
val x = flowX.first()
val y = flowY.first()
val z = flowZ.first()

println("$x, $y, $z") // this line is executed and prints the right values
```

Why would my flows emit with `first()` but not `combine()`?

Comment: You need a terminal operator to start the flow. `first()` is a terminal operator. You can also use `collect { ... }`, `toSet()`, `toList()`, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`combine()` is not a terminal flow operator. It only creates a new flow and returns it, but it doesn't start collecting the flow. You still need to collect the flow to actually start executing it:

```kotlin
combine(flowX, flowY, flowZ) { x, y, z ->
    println("$x, $y, $z")
}.collect {}
```

This solution seems a little strange to me, as it prints in the lambda that was supposed to transform the value, then it returns a flow of `Unit` and collects doing nothing. Alternatively, you can do it this way:

```kotlin
combine(flowX, flowY, flowZ) { x, y, z -> Triple(x, y, z) }
    .collect { (x, y, z) -> println("$x, $y, $z") }
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue combining 2 flows.

Seems - The combine operator may not be receiving values from both flows simultaneously.

By default, **the combine operator waits for both flows to emit at least one value before it starts combining them**. If one of the flows emits a value but the other flow doesn't, the collect block will not be triggered. Ensure that both flows are emitting values to trigger the collect block (suggested by ChatGPT): this was true in my case

Answer (score 0):

Flows should provide data. When you fetch data from both flows, you can combine them. For example:

```
val flow1 = flow{ emit("Hello world") }
val flow2 = flow<String>{ /* not emitting anything */ }

fun getDataFromFlows(): Flow<String> {
  return combine(flow1, flow2) { value1, value2 ->
    value1 + value2
  }
}
```

There is not an output. However, if you put emitting value such as on start step:

```
val flow1 = flow{ emit("Hello world") }
val flow2 = flow<String>{ 
  /* not emitting anything */ 
}.onStart { emit(" from Istanbul, Turkiye") }

fun getDataFromFlows(): Flow<String> {
  return combine(flow1, flow2) { value1, value2 ->
    value1 + value2
  }
}

Output: Hello world from Istanbul, Turkiye
```

Now you can get combined result. If you would like to try on browser, copy below and paste it on [Kotlin Online Editor](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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):

```
/**
 * @author: Caner Kaşeler
 * https://linktr.ee/canerkaseler
 */

import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.callbackFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.combine
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.map
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.onStart
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collectLatest
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

val flow1 = flow{ emit("Hello world") }
val flow2 = flow<String>{
    /* not emitting anything */
}.onStart { emit(" from Istanbul, Turkiye") }

fun getDataFromFlows(): Flow<String> {
    return combine(flow1, flow2) { value1, value2 ->
        value1 + value2
    }
}


fun main() {
    runBlocking<Unit> {
        getDataFromFlows().collectLatest { flowValue ->
            println(flowValue)
        }
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
Hello world from Istanbul, Turkiye
```